# Substituting fonts without changes to the source

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

For code snippets in documents, I prefer Bitstream Courier 10 Pitch, which is darker than the usual Monotype/Linotype Couriers.  Using fontspec, I say:

```
\setmonofont[Scale=0.92]{Courier 10 Pitch}
```

However, I often collaborate with people who don't want to use XeTeX, and who don't necessarily have a local copy of Bitstream's Courier.  So I use pdftex, and say

```
\usepackage{courier}
```

Is there a way to coerce pdftex into embedding Bitstream Courier instead of Nimbus Mono in the generated PDF?

**Addendum**: perhaps I should have given some more background.  We're speaking of exercise sheets for students, which are hosted in a shared *git* repository, and must be easy to compile by all of the tutors, many of who are not TeX specialists.  While I have no strong aversion to installing extra packages in my private TeX tree, the documents in the shared *git* repository must be compilable without installing anything that is not provided in TeXlive.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/bitstrea/courier

Comment: @Sverre, I would expect to be able to do this without installing anything — just tell the PDF driver to use a different font.

Comment: Where does it say that you need to install anything? Based on the [README file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/psfonts/bitstrea/courier/README), no installation is necessary. But you obviously need to download the fonts ...

Comment: It requires installing the tfms and friends in the texmf hierarchy.  I also requires changing the source document, which is what I don't want.

Comment: If you're prevented from putting TeX fonts in your TeX directory, I'm pretty sure you can't make TeX use those fonts. Moreover, I don't see why you're trying to do this. If your problem is that you're collaborating with people who don't have the Bitstream Courier font you're using , how will it help you to continue using that font with ``pdfTeX``?

Comment: The plan is for my co-authors to continue using the default Courier font.  I'd like to be able to produce the final version (using Bitstream Courier) without modifying the source manuscript.  Less important, but I'd also like to avoid making any permanent changes to my TeX installation.

Comment: Let me see if I get this right. There's a document with ``\usepackage{courier}`` (or smth similar) your colleagues are compiling with ``pdfLaTeX`` (I don't think you mean ``pdfTeX``). You want to compile the same document, _without making any changes to the ``.tex`` file_, and get a different font in the output than your colleagues get? My bet is that this cannot be achieved.

Comment: I bet it cannot be achieved without making changes to your TeX installation. (Changes which would at the very least involve copying files to your local or personal tree under false names in order to trick TeX into using one thing when you specified another.) I don't understand the motivation. It is one line in your source: surely it is several billion times easier to just have 2 lines in the source, commenting the one you don't want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19792/64016) solved my problem quite nicely.  I created a file called `10pitch.map` that contains the following lines:

```
pcrr8r Courier10PitchBT-Roman " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <c0419bt_.pfb
pcrr8rn Courier10PitchBT-Roman " .85 ExtendFont TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <c0419bt_.pfb
pcrro8r Courier10PitchBT-Italic " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <c0582bt_.pfb
pcrb8r Courier10PitchBT-Bold " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <c0583bt_.pfb
pcrbo8r Courier10PitchBT-BoldItalic " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <c0611bt_.pfb
```

Then I say

```
pdflatex '\pdfmapfile{=10pitch.map}\input{filename.tex}'
```

and the fonts get substituted at compilation time.